# css is not affecting in browser but working fine in GWT designer

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

i wrote css for a button its working fine in GWT designer and it showing the image.
but when i compile and run its not showing the image .
and i tried `getElement().getStyle()` but no use
i tried
`DOM.setStyleAttribute(btnNewButton.getElement(), "background", "url(../WEB-INF/btn.jpg)");` no use

please help me with this..

here's my css

```
.cancel {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-image: url( ../WEB-INF/btnCancel.jpg);

}
```

code..

```
Button btnNewButton = new Button("New button");

btnNewButton.setStyleName("cancelbutton");

btnNewButton.setText("cancel");
```

i am using GWT 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put files in the `WEB-INF` folder if you want to access them in a web page. The folder is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks... for your help ..found the solution...created new images folder and i placed all my images ther..now its working..problem is am not getting that button function..like when i press button will go down right..

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but guessing you want different images for different buttons states (like when down, different image). In that case take a look at PushButton, where you can set different state images.

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes in css.

```
background-image: url('../WEB-INF/btnCancel.jpg');
```

Should be a good matter. And make sure the image is not called 'btnCancel.JPG'.

Comment: But WEB-INF is not accessible in Browser. Also there is no problem with the quotes even if it is a Normal HTML Application.